# Shallow fetch for repository

Tags: continuous-integration, azure-devops, azure-pipelines

I have an Azure Pipeline (yaml) which uses templates and I'm trying to figure out how to setup the fetch depth of the actual repository being cloned.

```
resources:
  repositories:
    - repository: templates
      type: git
      name: 'DevOps/CICD'
      ref: refs/heads/develop
    - repository: self # sic!
      fetchDepth: 1
      clean: true`
```

Fetch depth is supported *(vscode extension)* but I can't seem to find any extensive [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/yaml-schema?view=vsts&tabs=schema#repository-resource) on it..

Comment: Just a comment for in case it's been missed so far, when you use templates it doesn't do a checkout of repo you reference, it just references those yaml files. The accepted answer mentions doing an actual checkout which would give you access to the other non yaml files from where you are referencing the template but are 2 different things 

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Placing this under `steps` works for me:

```
steps:
  - checkout: self
    fetchDepth: 1
    clean: true
  - task: NuGetCommand@2
  ...
```

Results in:

> 2019-01-17T09:21:45.1133753Z ##[command]git -c http.extraheader="AUTHORIZATION: bearer ***" fetch --tags --prune --progress --no-recurse-submodules --depth=1 origin

Comment: https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/294872/yaml-build-ignores-fetchdepth.html

Comment: NOTE: If you are using tags you may still be downloading more than you expect. You can disable tags by using "fetchTags: false" alongside "fetchDepth: 1" as seen in the above. I had the above step and could see "--depth=1" in my pipeline output, but it was still downloading too much, disabling tags fixed it for me!

Answer (score 11):

Another option is to add the [shallow fetch](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/repos/pipeline-options-for-git?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml#shallow-fetch) setting into the `Variables` section of your YAML pipeline:

```yaml
variables:
  Agent.Source.Git.ShallowFetchDepth: 1
```

Azure Pipelines will automatically recognize this setting and use it as a `--depth=1` argument when it does `git fetch`.

Note that this only applies to pipelines created before September 2022 – pipelines created after that date will [automatically fetch with a depth of 1](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/yaml-schema/steps-checkout?view=azure-pipelines#shallow-fetch), so it doesn't need to be explicitly configured.

Answer (score 5):

here's the link you are looking for: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/yaml-schema?view=vsts&tabs=schema#checkout

the property is fetchDepth indeed.

Comment: thanks! any idea where this should be set? (in yaml hierarchy)

Comment: pretty sure thats the root of the hierarchy, so at the first level

Comment: nvm, found it, under `steps`

Comment: not sure why it would be understeps, maybe if you need to checkout something directly in the phase

Comment: it doesnt have to be repository, it can be just repo (works for me across many builds)

Comment: just tested this under resources/repositories, no effect... trying under steps now

Comment: Confirm this works when under `steps`... `2019-01-17T09:21:45.1133753Z ##[command]git -c http.extraheader="AUTHORIZATION: bearer ***" fetch --tags --prune --progress --no-recurse-submodules --depth=1 origin`

Comment: It's set at the step level as not every job requires the same or any source code - for example non-deployment jobs don't checkout code by default, other steps may want to build a different repo.

Comment: links change and break, your answer is no longer relevant.