# SonarQube with shallow clone warning even with shallow disabled on Jenkins build

Tags: git, jenkins, sonarqube, shallow-clone

I have a Jenkins server building a solution using MSBuild. Shallow Clone is not enabled (on Advanced Clone Behaviours), so I supposed it's getting all the last commits. And I'm using SonarQube to analyze. I set to run the Begin Analysis before build and the End Analysis after build is complete. The SonarQube Analysis finishes successfully, but I'm receiving a warning:

> Shallow clone detected during the analysis. Some files will miss SCM
>   information.
>    This will affect features like auto-assignment of issues. Please
>   configure your build to disable shallow clone.

Someone knows what I'm missing to SonarQube works fine?

Comment: No usable info on the [documentation](https://docs.sonarqube.org/latest/analysis/scm-integration/) page?

Comment: Yes! I have read before, but now I check the info regarding a full clone, so I searched about that and posted now the answer :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have fixed! When I disabled the Shallow Clone on Jenkins, it was still missing the past commits, so I had to run some commands on GIT bash inside the repository folder:

```
git fetch --depth=1000000
```

(unless you have more than 1 million commits)

then to confirm that I have removed the shallow:

```
git fetch --unshallow
```

After wait the next build and analysis, now has disappeared the warning and I can see the authors!

Comment: That means ur using no more shallow clones after using this command. right?

Comment: `fatal: --unshallow on a complete repository does not make sense`

Answer (score 27):

I was getting the same warning in sonarcloud for one of my github repository integrated with sonarcloud.

[image: sonarcloud shallow clone warning github]

So if someone is looking for the option to disable shallow clone in github actions workflow, then just edit the `yml` file and use the `fetch-depth: 0` option with `actions/checkout@v2` step to disable shallow clone.

The complete example is mentioned below

```
    steps:
    - uses: actions/checkout@v2
      with:
        fetch-depth: 0
```

For more detailed information visit - https://github.com/actions/checkout#fetch-all-history-for-all-tags-and-branches

Comment: Any idea how to do the same on Azure DevOps?

Comment: @Zenith `fetchDepth: 1` https://stackoverflow.com/a/54232685/827472

Answer (score 3):

As described in documentation: https://docs.travis-ci.com/user/customizing-the-build#sts=Git%20Clone%20Depth%20#

Just disable *git fetch depth* limit in `.travis.yml` as follows:

```
git:
  depth: false
```

Otherwise you are git cloning twice.